# Hey i'm stuck at a question of summations which i don't understand how to prove

Tags: summation

The questions is to prove the following summation for every positive integer n:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(1+(-1)^i)=2n$$
https://i.ibb.co/dt77GGK/dx.png

Comment: Please do not [ask separate questions under one question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6464/posting-multiple-questions-as-one). You can edit to remove one of the questions, and ask a new question for the other one.

Comment: Some of the symbols in your question, I didn't even know existed... MathJax please...

Comment: [MathJax Tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: What values can $1+(-1)^i$ take ? Try several values, maybe $i=1,2,3,4,5$. Then can you rewrite the summation in a different form ?

Comment: Please show us what you tried and where you got stuck. Adding $1$, $2n$ times mustn't be difficult. Of you are confused about what's happening with $(-1)^i$ when you add it $2n$ times, just put $n=2$ or $n=3$ and make observations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{2n}{(1+(-1)^i)}=\sum_{i=1,i {\text{ odd}}}^{2n}{((-1)^i+1)}+\sum_{i=1,i {\text{ even}}}^{2n}{((-1)^i+1)}$$
What is $(-1)^i+1$ when $i$ is odd?

What is $(-1)^i+1$ when $i$ is even?

How many even numbers are there between $1$ and $2n$?

Comment: when i is even it is 2

Comment: When odd? $\quad$

Comment: it will be 0 when odd

Comment: Perfect. The first sum is therefore 0. Now note that we have n even numbers between 1 and 2n. Thus the second sum will be $2+2+...+2$ n times. Which will give what?

Comment: if we take 2 common then it will give out a series of 1+1...+n so it will be n and then multiply by 2 so it will be 2n

Comment: am i correct? or wrong

Comment: Correct. $\quad$

Answer (score 0):

The $(-1)^i$'s alternate and cancel out in pairs.  You just get $\sum_{i=1}^{2n}1=2n$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a candidate for "proof by induction"!  When n= 1 this is $\sum_{i=1}^2 (1+(-1)^i)= (1+ (-1)^1)+ (1+ (-1)^2)= (1- 1)+ (1+ 1)= 2= 2(1)$.

Now assume that, for some k, $\sum_{i=1}^{2k} (1+ (-1)^i)= 2k.  
 $\sum_{i= 1}^{2(k+ 1)}  (1+ (-1)^i)= \sum_{i=1}^{2k+2}\sum_{i=1}^k (1+ (-1)^i)+ (1+ (-1)^{k+1})+ (1+ (-1)^{k+2})= 2k+ (1+ (-1)^{k+1})+ (1+ (-1)^{k+2}$.

Complete this as two cases: k even or k odd.
If k is even then k+ 1 is odd and k+2 is even.  The sum is 2k+ (0)+ (2)= 2k+ 2= 2(k+1).

If k is odd then k+ 1 is even and k+ 2 is odd.  The sum is 2k+ (2)+ (0)= 2k+ 2= 2(k+ 1).